# PHP date method returning an hour early

Tags: php, date, timezone

So I have set my timezone at the top of my file with: `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');`

I have updated my timezonedb with pecl to 2015.7 and added the extension to my php.ini and restarted my server. I now show that version when using `timezone_version_get()`.

I also var dump out (`date_default_timezone_get()`) just to make sure I have the correct timezone set and it in fact outputs `America/New_York`

Yet when I Use `date('H:i:s');` it is showing an hour behind. Any ideas?

Comment: Tried working fine. Can you show more of your code work.

Comment: Thank you guys. I decided to move my sets / gets and var_dumps down to RIGHT before the date call instead of at the top of the file. Unfortunately this is legacy code and their seems to be something messing with the timezone in the spaghetti mess.

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

echo date("Y-m-d h:iA");
```

Working fine, Simple try this.

Comment: I was already trying this. Unfortunately I do not think this question or answer will be useful to anyone due to the nature of what was wrong...but I will leave it up just in case. If your testing your timezones / dates make sure to do it RIGHT before the date() call especially if you are working on procedural code.